# Why can't I write to the file mmaped

Tags: c, mmap, memory-mapped-files

First I create a file and echo some characters to it, and cat the file it shows:

sasdfasdfas

asfdasfsadf

Then in the C program, I open the file with :

```
int fd=open("file",O_RDWR);
```

mmaped the file with:

```
unsigned char *addr=mmap(NULL,length,PROT_WRITE,MAP_PRIVATE,fd,pa_offset);
```

where length is a int about the size of the file abtained by fstat, and pa_offset is 0.

The open function and mmap function all return well, that are, the open returns a positive integer like 3, and the mmap returns a proper address like 0x7fd36999d000.

I read the file from the addr and everything is OK. When I write to it, it seems write succesfully as I print the memory in the program, but the actual file content is not changed if I cat it.

I have tried some efforts like using msync(),  but all have the same result.

Who of you would be kind to tell me where I was stumbled? I just want to write to the file from mmap-_-

Comment: Just because x86 does not have write-permission without read-permission does not mean you should read from memory `mmap()ed` write-only.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You want `MAP_SHARED` rather than `MAP_PRIVATE`.

```
unsigned char *addr=mmap(NULL,length,PROT_WRITE,MAP_PRIVATE,fd,pa_offset);
                                                ↑↑↑↑↑↑↑↑↑↑↑
```

From the [GNU C library manual](http://www.gnu.org/software/libc/manual/html_node/Memory_002dmapped-I_002fO.html) (emphasis mine):

> `MAP_PRIVATE` -
>   **This specifies that writes to the region should never be
>   written back to the attached file.** Instead, a copy is made for the
>   process, and the region will be swapped normally if memory runs low.
>   No other process will see the changes.
>
> `MAP_SHARED` - 
>   **This specifies that writes to the region will be written
>   back to the file.** Changes made will be shared immediately with other
>   processes mmaping the same file.
>   Note that actual writing may take place at any time. You need to use
>   `msync`, described below, if it is important that other processes using
>   conventional I/O get a consistent view of the file.

See [`man mmap`](http://linux.die.net/man/2/mmap).

Put another way, `MAP_PRIVATE` divorces the mapped memory from the backing file by using [copy-on-write](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Copy-on-write).